# JUnit testing with hard coded database queries

Tags: junit

Can I use JUnit for unit testing when the function I want to test contains hard coded database queries (these are written in Java).

Comment: Yes, you can. Why couldn't you? Junit doesn't care what your code does.

Comment: but then then my unit tests will change the database states.

Comment: A common practice is to use an in-memory database for tests that you can easily reset. E.g. [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a database instance via Docker before running your tests. For example, I can use [Gradle Docker Compose Plugin](https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin) to start a PostgreSQL server before testings. The database schema update is conducted automatically by Liquibase during Spring Boot initialization.

Note that you have to make sure the database states is clean or under control before running every test.